# Problema a referenciar claves en IBM informix

Tags: sql, informix

Mi situación es la siguiente.
Estructura:

```
Grupo (GrupoId, GrupoNombre)
Asignatura (AsignaturaId, AsignaturaNombre)
GrupoTieneAsignatura (GrupoId, AsignaturaID)
Planilla(GrupoId(de grupotieneasignatura), AsignaturaID(de grupotieneasignatura), otros)
```

Como se puede ver en la estructura intento referenciar una clave se podría decir en cascada. Pero al momento de referenciar en la ultima me da error. ¿Por qué puede ser?

El codigo que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
  CREATE TABLE asignatura  ( 
    asignaturaid        SERIAL NOT NULL,
    asignaturanombre    VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    asignaturaestado    BOOLEAN DEFAULT T,
    areaid              INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(asignaturaid)
);
CREATE TABLE grupo  ( 
    grupoid         SERIAL NOT NULL,
    gruponombre     VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    grupocantidad   SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    grupoestado     BOOLEAN DEFAULT T,
    PRIMARY KEY(grupoid)
);

CREATE TABLE grupotieneasignatura (
asignaturaid INTEGER NOT NULL,
grupoid INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(asignaturaid, grupoid)
);

CREATE TABLE planilla  ( 
    diaid           INTEGER NOT NULL,
    horaid          INTEGER NOT NULL,
    personaci       CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    aulaid          INTEGER,
    asignaturaid    INTEGER,
    grupoid         INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(diaid,horaid,aulaid,personaci)
);
ALTER TABLE grupotieneasignatura
    ADD CONSTRAINT ( FOREIGN KEY(grupoid)
    REFERENCES grupo(grupoid) CONSTRAINT ex1
     );
ALTER TABLE grupotieneasignatura
    ADD CONSTRAINT ( FOREIGN KEY(asignaturaid)
    REFERENCES asignatura(asignaturaid) CONSTRAINT ex2
     );
ALTER TABLE planilla
    ADD CONSTRAINT ( FOREIGN KEY(personaci)
    REFERENCES persona(personaci) CONSTRAINT externapersona
    );
ALTER TABLE planilla
    ADD CONSTRAINT ( FOREIGN KEY(grupoid)
    REFERENCES grupotieneasignatura(grupoid) CONSTRAINT externagrupo
     );
ALTER TABLE planilla
    ADD CONSTRAINT ( FOREIGN KEY(aulaid)
    REFERENCES aula(aulaid) CONSTRAINT externaaula
     );
ALTER TABLE planilla
    ADD CONSTRAINT ( FOREIGN KEY(asignaturaid)
    REFERENCES grupotieneasignatura(asignaturaid) CONSTRAINT externaasignatura
     );
```

El error que me esta arrojando al ejecutar estas intruscciones sql es el siguiente:

> No se encuentra clave primaria o restriccion de tipo unico en la tabla (grupotieneasignatura).

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: publica el script mínimo de creación y el error que te da. Te recomiendo leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

El error debe provenir de esta sentencia:

```
ALTER TABLE planilla
ADD CONSTRAINT ( FOREIGN KEY(grupoid)
REFERENCES grupotieneasignatura(grupoid) CONSTRAINT externagrupo
 );
```

o esta:

```
ALTER TABLE planilla
ADD CONSTRAINT ( FOREIGN KEY(asignaturaid)
REFERENCES grupotieneasignatura(asignaturaid) CONSTRAINT externaasignatura
 );
```

En ambos casos, estás tratando de crear una clave foránea hacia `grupotieneasignatura` pero para una columna que **por sí sola** no es definida como clave primaria ni una clave única (nota lo que el error te dice).

Como la clave primaria para `grupotieneasignatura` es la combinación de **ambas** columnas `grupoid` y `asignaturaid`, lo más probable es que lo que realmente quieres es definir **una sola clave foránea que combine ambas columnas.**

De modo que, en vez de las 2 sentencias mencionadas arriba, reemplázalas con la siguiente:

```
alter table planilla
add constraint (
  foreign key(asignaturaid, grupoid)
  references grupotieneasignatura(asignaturaid, grupoid)
  constraint externaasignaturagrupo
);
```

Puede que la sintaxis que usé no sea perfecta, pero la idea debería funcionar.

Otra posibilidad es que en realidad sí quieres 2 claves foráneas separadas, pero no hacia la tabla `grupotieneasignatura`. En este caso, probablemente quieres que las claves refieran a las 2 tablas `grupo` y `asignatura` por separado.

Si este es el caso, puedes modifcar las 2 sentencias con las siguientes:

```
ALTER TABLE planilla
ADD CONSTRAINT ( FOREIGN KEY(grupoid)
REFERENCES grupo(grupoid) CONSTRAINT externagrupo
 );

ALTER TABLE planilla
ADD CONSTRAINT ( FOREIGN KEY(asignaturaid)
REFERENCES asignatura(asignaturaid) CONSTRAINT externaasignatura
 );
```

Dejo contigo decidir cuál de las 2 opciones es la correcta para ti.